# Randomly Got a green streak on my moniter, Can I fix it?

Tags: helpfile

I am fairly new to this. So I will tell you whats wrong. So today I turned on my computer and right when I got to the Ubuntu start up page it has this weird green streak down the computer. It wasn't there late last night! I really need help, I don't know what it is, how to fix it, can I fix it, how it got there, or anything but that it is green, Its not on the out side of the screen, and I can only see it when my computer is on. Please help! I am using the newer Edge Ubuntu 14 something, it has been working fine but this today, it might not even be the system. Still I need help, Please!
Update: It also does not show the green mark when I take a screen shot.

Comment: Does the same green streak also appear on your monitor when you are running a live Linux distro from a DVD or USB or booting the computer from a Windows installation disk?

Comment: It just started doing this today. It wasn't doing it yesterday, or it wasn't here yesterday  when I was using the computer. I use it a lot for school and I don't know what you mean a linux distro or anything else. It doesn't have windows anymore I took it off.

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1. a hardware problem 2. a software problem. You can eliminate the software problem as a cause of the green streak by booting your computer with another bootable OS from a DVD or USB. If the green streak does not appear when you boot your computer from a different OS disk, then you have a software problem. Two different OSs and the problem only appears with one of them means that the problem is specific to the Ubuntu OS that is installed on your hard drive. Maybe you know someone who can lend you an OS installation disk for long enough to boot your computer with it

Comment: Awe, this is so bad..... Are you sure? I can't boot it with something else yet. I was planning on putting Debian on it this week though. What do you mean when you say software problem?

Comment: A problem that is caused by software, for example the operating system, can be fixed by making the appropriate change to the software, without it being necessary to make any changes in the computer's hardware. I hope this explains this matter thoroughly enough for you.

Comment: Well thank you for telling me all of this. I am going to try one more thing, I am going to keep it off for like an hour and see if it still there when I turn it back on. If it helps some of it has gone, but not all of it just little spots of the tiny line. I will get back to you if it works or not. Thank you for what you have told me! :)

Comment: Try opening the terminal and running `xrandr`. Running that typically resets screen settings, so if there's a software error , it might help it. Another is to press Ctrl + Alt + F2 to go to virtual terminal and then back to GUI with Ctrl + Alt + F7.

Comment: didnt work but thanks, I  think Karels right it might be my monitor then. @Serg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green streak does not show when you take a screenshot. I think you have a problem with your monitor. Can you borrow another monitor to test Ubuntu with it?

Comment: How can that be when it was perfect at like 12am? I didn't even do anything to it. All I did was turn the computer on this morning. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I don't know how to fix computer monitors.

Comment: Its a broken screan